# Change image src to a local image using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

First time ever touching javascript here, so bear with me.
My file structure looks like so:
[image]

I want to change the image in my HTML using js. Here's the relevant HTML code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Assignment 3A</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/assignment_3.css">
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="data/data.js"></script>
        <script src="script/htmlMaker.js"></script>
        <script src="script/assignment_3.js"></script>
        <script id="news-detail-template" type="text/html">
                    <img class='news_photo' src='{{photo}}' >
        <div class='news_heading'>{{heading}}</div>
        <div class='date'>{{Date}}</div>
        <div class='news_detail'>{{details}}</div>          
        </script>  
        <script id="news-item-template" type="text/html">
        <div news_id='{{id}}' class='news_item' > {{heading}} </div> 
        <img class='news_img' src='data/NBA.jpg'>
        </script>         
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="newsDiv">
            <div class="left">Latest</div>
            <div id="news" class="marquee"></div>
            <img id="toggle" class="right" src="data/pause.png" onclick="toggle(this)">
        </div>
        <div id="detail" class="detail">

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And then the corresponding js code in assignment_3.js:

```
function toggle(image) {
    if (image.src != "data/pause.png")
    {
        image.src='data/pause.png';
    }
    else if (image.src == "data/pause.png")
    {
        image.src='data/play.png';
    }
}
```

Obviously, something is amiss here, as the browser doesn't seem to recognize my image paths at all. How would I go about doing this correctly?

Comment: Where did you link the script to your HTML?

Comment: @Tatiana ahh, I'll update the HTML with all the code. But it's linked there.
<script src="script/assignment_3.js"></script>

Comment: Your snippet has several errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `image.src`, it returns the full path of the image. In the `if` condition, you only checks the relative path of the image. To check for the relative path of the image, you can use `image.getAttribute('src')`.

```js
function toggle(image) {
  if (image.getAttribute('src') == "data/pause.png") {
    image.setAttribute('src', 'data/play.png');
  } else {
    image.setAttribute('src', 'data/pause.png');
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="newsDiv">
    <div class="left">Latest</div>
    <div id="news" class="marquee"></div>
    <img id="toggle" class="right" src="data/pause.png" onclick="toggle(this)">
  </div>
  <div id="detail" class="detail">

  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have modelled a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your problem in [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e4b263q8/). I don't see any issues in your toggle logic. The only thing you need to consider is using `img.getAttribute('src')` instead of `img.src`. This is because

- `img.getAttribute('src')` - Gives you the actual value that the HTML markup has set
- `img.src` - Effective absolute path of the source

```
function toggle(img) {
  // var playSrc = "data/play.png"; // to use your file instead
  var playSrc = "https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/premium/png-256-thumb/play-button-1516951-1285078.png";

// var pauseSrc = "data/pause.png"; // to use your file instead
  var pauseSrc = "http://www.pngall.com/wp-content/uploads/5/Pause-Button-Transparent.png";

  if (img.getAttribute('src') != pauseSrc)
  {
    img.setAttribute('src', pauseSrc);
  }
  else // The part if (image.src == "data/pause.png") is redundant
  {
    img.setAttribute('src', playSrc);
  }
}
```

With that out of the way, you have a lot of junk in the `<head>` tag, which you need to remove (I have put them below). Probably, the code isn't working because of that.

```
<script id="news-detail-template" type="text/html">
                    <img class='news_photo' src='{{photo}}' >
        <div class='news_heading'>{{heading}}</div>
        <div class='date'>{{Date}}</div>
        <div class='news_detail'>{{details}}</div>          
        </script>  
        <script id="news-item-template" type="text/html">
        <div news_id='{{id}}' class='news_item' > {{heading}} </div> 
        <img class='news_img' src='data/NBA.jpg'>
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

As Harshana points out, you need to use the `getAttribute` function to check equality. You can set the image source using a regular assignment operator, but you cant use `==` to check for equality.